# Change GPIO Pin usage of PIR Motion Sensor

Tags: gpio, python, motion

I'm Using a PIR Motion Sensor. I found a plenty of tutorials how to connect this module to the Pi. But they have always the same usage of GPOI Pins. Is there any way to change the Pins used for this module in the script( http://pastebin.com/ije9XvZK ). Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can.

Just change all GPIO number occurrences to the number of the GPIO you want to use.